# Get streaming stats for each node inside IPFS cluster?

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm using ipfs for video files storage and streaming , inside the cluster there are 4 nodes by now and anyone can join the cluster as ipfs node and can provide streaming for rewards.

I need the information that how we can calculate streaming provided by any particular node since beginning so we can reward them each month ?

what are the possible solutions ?
reference from doc would be helpful as well.